# Implementing IValueConverter in the Window's code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to define a converter for some of the controls on my `Window`. The way I (and most people) usually do it is define the converter **in its own class**, instantiate an instance of that class in `Window.Resources` and then use it. The problem in this particular case is that the converter needs to access the window's `DataContext`,so I decided to implement it in the window's code behind:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window, IValueConverter
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Other operations  
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Access the DataContext and return a value
        return new object();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to use it in XAML now. Obviously I don't want to instantiate a new instance of this class since I would lose the data context.
I tried

`"{Binding ElementName=someElement, Path=SomeProperty, Converter={Binding ElementName=myWindow}"`

Where `myWindow` is the name of this window. I get a runtime error saying:

```
"A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Converter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not entirely clear here - what does it mean to "needs to access the Window's DataContext?"  Do you mean you need to convert "DataContext.SomeProperty"?

Comment: No. In the `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods, I need to access the window's DataContext.

Comment: When you declare the ValueConverter as a resource, you can set properties on the object.  You could make a DataContext property on the ValueConverter and set it.  You might have to make the ValueConverter inherit from DependencyObject, and the property might need to be a DependencyProperty to do this.

Comment: Let me ask another way.  What property are you binding (is it in this Window, or a separate class), and what do you need the DataContext for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem in this particular case is that the converter needs to access the window's DataContext,so I decided to implement it in the window's code behind

One option would be to make the `IValueConverter` it's own class, and create an instance in XAML as you normally would.  If you make the converter a `DependencyObject`, you could add a dependency property for a `UIElement`, and bind the Window (`myWindow`) to the property.  This would allow the converter to have access to the Window (via it's property) in order to fetch the DataContext.

The converter could just be referenced as normal within the binding in this design.

Comment: How can I access the property from XAML? I still can't use binding. `Converter={Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=MyConverter}` fails.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I misunderstood what you were after - edited to provide a different alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I think MultiValueConverter can solve your problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx.
In your situation, beside **SomeProperty**, you can pass DataContext of the window to the converter and do whatever you want.